# How do I use SDL to blit an image in multiply mode?

Tags: c, sdl, blit

In Pygame, there is a special_flags argument to surface.blit. This let you combine pixels in ways different than simply copying them. For example, the multiply mode lets you multiply the pixels together.

How do I achieve this using SDL from C? I've looked at the SDL documentation, and I don't see any obvious ways of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

[Manually](http://www.seul.org/viewcvs/viewcvs.cgi/trunk/src/alphablit.c?rev=2265&root=PyGame&view=markup); see SoftBlitPyGame().